# SSIS FTP Package - Truncation 5KB through SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssms, ssms-addin

I'm new to SSIS and am in need of some expert help!

I've created an SSIS package that uploads a .txt file to a FTP site.  I've then Stored the Package in SSMS Integration Services, and created a SQL Server Agent job to run the package on a schedule to upload the .txt file to the FTP.  The package executes perfectly and the file is uploaded to the FTP as expected, however the .txt file is truncated to 5KB on every upload!   I'm not sure if I'm missing a setting in SSMS or what, when executing the package in BIDS it loads correctly and doesn't truncate so I'm guessing it has to be something with SSMS Integration settings?

Any help in resolving this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Ryan